How to use a finetuned LLM with langchain?
I'm working on fine-tuning an LLM like LLAMA2 or LLAMA3 on a specific task which is recommendation of questionnaires depending on the purpose of the study and the data researchers want to collect.
How do I use Langchain on a fine-tuned model? I guess I can always upload it to Huggingface and go from there but my company can't allow me to upload a fine-tuned model there.
What other solutions do I have?would Ollama be a solution to that problem if the model is uploaded on the cloud?

Langchain can run models stored locally. You could start from here.

Try seeing if you can run your model using llama-cpp or Ollama with a custom model
